# Site Login with HttpClient

Tags: java, post, authentication, httpclient

So I am using this code to login to the website posted...
and its not working.
In fact, it returns no status, just a 200 and the login site. ???

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

public class GetCookiePrintAndSetValue {

    public GetCookiePrintAndSetValue() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter(
                  HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT,
                  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2"
              );
        client.getState().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("https://gs.bcp.pinnacle,org", 443, "ANY_REALM"),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("214416", "PassWord")
        );
        PostMethod get = new PostMethod("https://gs.bcp.org/Pinnacle/piv/logon.aspx");
        get.setDoAuthentication( true );
        try {
            int status = client.executeMethod( get );
            System.out.println(status + "\n" + get.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the 200 is the status: [Http Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). 200 beeing OK

Answer (score 1):

I guess the authscope should be done on the same host as the request:
Oh! and the realm should be the constant AuthScope.ANY_REALM:

```
    client.getState().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope("gs.bcp.org", 443, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("214416", "PassWord")
    );
```

But perhaps the web site doesn't allow basic authentication.